# Borrar de un texto la palabra seleccionada por el usuario

Tags: javascript, html

Esto es lo único que me falta para finalizar mi proyecto, necesito saber como podría quitar una frase que el usuario introduzca por teclado, esto mediante una función activada por un botón.

Sé que una imagen vale más que mil palabras, así que dejaré una explicación gráfica de que quiero que pase.

> Adelanto que ya sé que mi función borrar está mal, es por eso que pido ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por supuesto, el código que estoy usando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Unir con salto de linea</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div name="head" class="h">
<table>
<tr>
<form name="prueba" autocomplete="off">
   <td><strong>Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA" /></td></strong>
   <td><strong>Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB" /></td></strong>
<td><select id="sel" required>
  <option value="1">Concatenar</option>
  <option value="0">Borrar</option>
</select></td>
 </table>
</form>
</div>
</tr>
<script>
function unirTexto(){
var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var rt=document.getElementById('resultado');
  var copia=  document.getElementById('respuesta');
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {html += c1 +' '+ p[i] +' '+ c2 + "\n"; copia.innerHTML = html; }}
function limpiar() {
document.getElementById('textA').value ="";
document.getElementById('textB').value ="";
document.getElementById('textC').value ="";
document.getElementById('respuesta').innerHTML ="";
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 if($(sel).val() == "0") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(sel).val() == "1") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
});
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
 if($(this).val() == "0") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(this).val() == "1") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
});
function borrarTexto(){
var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var rt=document.getElementById('resultado');
  var copia=  document.getElementById('respuesta');
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {html += p[i]+ "\n"; copia.innerHTML = html; }}
  function cambia(){
    document.respuesta.value.split(".").join(",");
}
</script>
<button onclick="unirTexto()" id="unir">Unir</button>
<button onclick="borrarTexto()" id="borrar">Borrar</button>
<button onclick="limpiar()" id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Contenido Medio</strong></td>
<td><strong>Resultado</strong></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td><textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="91" rows="33"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea id="respuesta" type="text" cols="91" rows="33" placeholder="El resultado se mostrará acá"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué problema tiene tu código???

Comment: Hola de nuevo Gabriel. Para dejar claro una cosa, en tu código tienes 2 campos. Cual es el que quieres leer para que borre la palabra seleccionada?

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Mi función borrar está incompleta y no sé como terminar de teclear lo que necesito

Comment: @ManucoBianco Como lo muestro en la imagen, me gustaría que sirviera para quitar la primera palabra o frase (el primer campo) y para quitar la útima palabra o frase (segundo campo)

Comment: Estoy probando tu codigo y tengo una pregunta, cuando vayas a borrar las frases que vas a borrar las deberia de tomar de los imput primea frase y ultima frase?

Comment: Exacto, debería de tomar los datos de los input, buscarlos dentro del textarea y mostrar la versión sin el contenido de los input en el textarea final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tienes incluido jQuery asumo que está bien usarlo

Cambios:

- Cambié donde estableces el evento del botón.
- Cambié el ciclo for por un `.each()`

La comprobación la hago usando los métodos de JS `startsWith()` y `endsWith()`

```js
function unirTexto(){
var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var rt=document.getElementById('resultado');
  var copia=  document.getElementById('respuesta');
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {html += c1 +' '+ p[i] +' '+ c2 + "\n"; copia.innerHTML = html; }};
function limpiar() {
document.getElementById('textA').value ="";
document.getElementById('textB').value ="";
document.getElementById('textC').value ="";
document.getElementById('respuesta').innerHTML ="";
};
function borrarTexto(){

var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var rt=document.getElementById('resultado');
  var copia=  document.getElementById('respuesta');
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  var html = "";
  var s="";
  $(p).each(function(){
    let s=this;
   if(s.startsWith(c1)) {
    s=s.replace(c1,"");
  }
  if(s.endsWith(c2)) {
    s=s.replace(c2,"");
  }
   html+=s+"\n";
    
  })
  $("#respuesta").val(html);
 
  }
  
  function cambia(){
    document.respuesta.value.split(".").join(",");
};

$(document).ready(function() {

 if($(sel).val() == "0") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(sel).val() == "1") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
 
 $('#sel').change(function() {


 if($(this).val() == "0") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(this).val() == "1") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
});

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Unir con salto de linea</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div name="head" class="h">
<table>
<tr>
<form name="prueba" autocomplete="off">
   <td><strong>Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA" /></td></strong>
   <td><strong>Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB" /></td></strong>
<td><select id="sel" required>
  <option value="1">Concatenar</option>
  <option value="0">Borrar</option>
</select></td>
 </table>
</form>
</div>
</tr>

<button onclick="unirTexto()" id="unir">Unir</button>
<button onclick="borrarTexto()" id="borrar">Borrar</button>
<button onclick="limpiar()" id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Contenido Medio</strong></td>
<td><strong>Resultado</strong></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td><textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="15" rows="33"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea id="respuesta" type="text" cols="15" rows="33" placeholder="El resultado se mostrará acá"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```